# IE 7 display issue with background image buttons

Tags: html, css

At the very bottom of the page the three read more buttons aren't displaying correctly in IE 7. Why is this? I have tried everything!

http://tjonesandson.co.uk/

```
.readmore {
  background-image: url("images/readmore-left3.png");
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.readmore a {
  background: url("images/readmore-right3.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
  color: #414040;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 21px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  padding: 3px 10px 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: I've got XP/SP3+IE7 here, and it looks the same as Win2k3+IE8. What looks wrong to you?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the this.
Set the display of a to inline-block ( you may need decrease the padding-top and bottom)

```
.readmore a {display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `display: block` on the `a` tag then that fixes your issue. Inline elements don't normally have vertical padding which is why it looks different in IE. You have to make it behave by changing it to a block level element. Adding `display: block` will fix it.

Answer (score -2):

Try using Strict instead of Transitional... transitional is not much better (if not the same as) quirks mode.

Comment: No it's not. As long as the `doctype` is valid it will trigger standard compliance mode.

Comment: Ok I've inserted <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 
But IE 7 is still showing the an overflow on the buttons.

Comment: @Zoidberg. Facts checked, all available sources points to me being correct. You can go tell them that too, if you want, starting with Wikipedia... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes

Comment: I have tried the overflow:hidden; but that didn't work, I have posted the CSS I'm using.

Comment: Ok now I have replaced the background image with just CSS.